# What does this error say? hdfs.DFSClient (DFSInputStream.java:doRead(849)) - zero

Tags: hadoop, log4j, hdfs, hadoop2

I'm running an app, which reads from HDFS storage. Everything is OK, but I see such warnings in the console:

```
2018-01-16 05:23:19,251 WARN  hdfs.DFSClient (DFSInputStream.java:doRead(849)) - zero
2018-01-16 05:23:19,264 WARN  hdfs.DFSClient (DFSInputStream.java:doRead(849)) - zero
2018-01-16 05:23:19,272 WARN  hdfs.DFSClient (DFSInputStream.java:doRead(849)) - zero
2018-01-16 05:23:22,991 WARN  hdfs.DFSClient (DFSInputStream.java:doRead(849)) - zero
2018-01-16 05:23:23,003 WARN  hdfs.DFSClient (DFSInputStream.java:doRead(849)) - zero
2018-01-16 05:23:23,012 WARN  hdfs.DFSClient (DFSInputStream.java:doRead(849)) - zero
```

What do they mean? I tried to redirect those messages to the log file, but nothing worked.

```
hadoop.root.logger="WARN,DRFA"
hadoop.log.dir=.
hadoop.log.file=hadoop.log
```

Is there a way to get rid of those warnings?

Comment: Which version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.9.0

Comment: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.9.0-RC3/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSInputStream.java